# angularjs: multiple watches

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following watch:

```
 $scope.$watch('[gridService.gridOptions.pagingOptions.currentPage, gridService.gridOptions.pagingOptions.pageSize]', function (newVal, oldVal, e) {
     if (newVal !== oldVal) {
          $scope.search();
     }
 }, true);
```

I have two questions:

1. if pageSize changes, I want to set the value of currentPage to 1. If I do that, I'm going to trigger the watch on currentPage. How do I prevent that ?
2. how do I check which of the two has triggered the watch ?  If I want to set the currentPage to 1 when pageSize changes, I need to know that pageSize triggered the watch. Do I need two separate watches in this case ?

Comment: It would be better to have separate watch, since you logic changes on which element is changed.

Answer (score 1):

checkout these fiddles; they both accomplish what you ask, one with the complex watch (slightly different than yours), one with the separate.

http://jsfiddle.net/rZxEc/ → Complex watch

http://jsfiddle.net/SM5aB/ → Two watches

The principle is the same: A variable that remembers whether the page change is caused by a page size change. The enclosing anonymous function just hides `var triggeredByPageSize` by the rest of the code:

```
(function() {
    var triggeredByPageSize
    // set $watches here
})();
```

I think the separate watches (fiddle 2) are cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

to watch multiple properties here are two things to consider you can pass a string array like this:

```
$scope.$watch('[someproperty,someproperty2,someproperty3]',function(new,old){
    //do something
},true);
```

the "true" at the end specifies that you want to deep watch an object so lets say you had a large object with many sub properties and you wanted to watch for any change to the parent object including if a sub property changes if you don't pass true it won't pick up if a sub property changes.

you asked which one made the change of the arry i believe you access that by adding the index at the end of new:

```
$scope.$watch('[someproperty,someproperty2,someproperty3]',function(new,old){
    console.log(new[0]);
    console.log(new[1]);
},true);
```